# Spring Security simple application

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Hi I am new in Spring Security but I have some experience in working with spring, I followed the tutorial on mkyong.com website for creating simple application in Spring 3.07 and it worked fine
But when I tried to add annotations "@secured ('ROLE_ADMIN')", I found error "can't create loginCOntroller bean"
Can anybody pointout error or provide me simple SPring security application
Here is my code

web.xml

```
    <web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

    <!-- Spring MVC -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
                    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
                </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

     <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
                  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
                </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml,
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
                  org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
                </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

springsecurity.xml (dispatcher servlet)

```
     <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:s="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">   


 <s:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />
 <s:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <s:intercept-url pattern="/index.jsp" access="permitAll" />
    <s:intercept-url pattern="/welcome*" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <s:intercept-url pattern="/helloadmin*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <s:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/welcome"
        authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
    <s:logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
</s:http>
<bean id="LoginController" class="com.mkyong.common.controller.LoginController" />
<s:authentication-manager>
  <s:authentication-provider>
    <s:user-service>
        <s:user name="joseph" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <s:user name="jane" password="123456" authorities="ROLE_USER" />          
    </s:user-service>
  </s:authentication-provider>
</s:authentication-manager>
</beans>
```

mvc dispatcher servlet.xml

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mkyong.common.controller" >
    </context:component-scan>
    <bean
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
      </property>
      <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
      </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

logincontroller.java

```
    @Controller
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/welcome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model, Principal principal) {

        String name = principal.getName();
        model.addAttribute("username", name);
        model.addAttribute("message", "Spring Security Custom Form example");
        return "hello";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(ModelMap model) {

        return "login";

    }

    // @Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
     @RequestMapping(value="/delete", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String DeleteAll(ModelMap model, Principal principal ) {
        return "deleteUsers";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/loginfailed", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginerror(ModelMap model) {

        model.addAttribute("error", "true");
        return "login";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String logout(ModelMap model) {

        return "login";

    }

    }
```

COde in present state execute successfully but when i remove comment of @Secured('ROLE_ADMIN') code shows error  can't create logincontroller bean
Can anybody tell what i am missing or provide me code of simple Spring SEcurity application

Comment: Why not start with the sample applications that come with the project itself?

Comment: What is the entire stacktrace of the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Works ok for me. But I'm using 3.1.0.RELEASE and not 3.0.7. Also, please check your imports. It should be import org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Secured;

Comment: thanks for the reply I will check it :)
I already wasted my 2 days on google searching for this error

Comment: can u share me project you created on uploadserver or by email, my email is janejosephene@gmail.com
I am still out of luck still facing same error :(

Comment: I guess I have not added correct jar files
Can you tell me which jars are required

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this: `@Secured({"ROLE_ADMIN"})`

Comment: Did not worked same error
I guess I have not added correct jar files
Can you tell me which jars are required

Comment: Provide us the error log, so that I can tell you what `.jar` file you need.